# Mongodb Is Not Opening

Tags: mongodb

When I am trying to open `mongodb` in windows 10, it closes immediately.The window shows connecting to host and the window closes immediately.

> connecting to:
> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt
> failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused
> by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed exiting with code 1

This is the error showing while opening `mongoDB`

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: To allow the community to help you better, please provide more context - did you install mongoDB as a Windows service or not, how are you currently running it, what steps did you take to fix the problem, have you tried re-installing it, how far did you get with the installation docs - `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/`

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide error as formatted text. Did you check the log file? A very common problem is that the data directory does not exist. On Windows the default dbPath is `\data\db`

Comment: Did you start the MonogDB service?